# Sql statement something wrong in INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

heres my query :

```
$sql = " `SELECT excelsis_news_events.images.filename as f, excelsis_news_events.event.event_name as en , excelsis_news_events.event.event_date as dd ,excelsis_news_events.event.event_desc as descri ".
                               " FROM excelsis_news_events.images ".
                               " INNER JOIN excelsis_news_events.event ".
                               " WHERE excelsis_news_events.images.event_id = excelsis_news_events.event.event_id ".
                               " GROUP BY excelsis_news_events.event.event_name ".
                               " ORDER BY event_date` ";
```

it is retrieving images but the problem is it is only retrieving 1 image per event. I needed to get all images with an event_id  equal to the event_id in database event.

Output should be

event name     images

----------     ----------
event 1        event_id = 1 ( filenam1.jpg , filenmae2.jpg , filename3.jpg )
event 2        event_id = 2 ( filename1.jpg , filename.2jpg , filename_3.jpg )

but the problem is it only retrieves one image per event.

Comment: Shouldn't your `INNER JOIN` have an `ON` clause to specify the join?

Comment: Have a look at each table separately.  Make sure there are, in fact, many images for each event.

Comment: Why is there a `GROUP BY`? The select list has no aggregate function.

Comment: I've tried but still retrieving one image per event

Comment: yes. theres atleast 5 images per event.

Comment: remove the group by and add a ON clause to the INNER JOIN statement

Comment: I've changed. it is retrieving all images now. but i wanted to sort them by event. its like an album.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    excelsis_news_events.images.filename as f
    ,excelsis_news_events.event.event_name as en 
    ,excelsis_news_events.event.event_date as dd 
    ,excelsis_news_events.event.event_desc as descri 
FROM 
    excelsis_news_events.event
    INNER JOIN excelsis_news_events.images
        ON excelsis_news_events.images.event_id = excelsis_news_events.event.event_id  
ORDER BY 
    excelsis_news_events.event.event_name
    , excelsis_news_events.event.event_date
```

If you are looking for somthing else, edit your question, we need to the expected output.